# React is not showing anything on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was using function instead of class and the code was working up to certain extent, now it is not displaying at all.

In my VehiclesList.js I generate 10 random vehicles, code below:

```
import React from 'react'
import {faker} from '@faker-js/faker'
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import Vehicles from './Vehicles';

class VehicleList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.manufacturer = this.faker.vehicle.manufacturer().bind(this)
  }

   render(){
   return (
    <div style={{ display: 'block', width: 400, padding: 30 }}>
        <ListGroup>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</ListGroup.Item>
      </ListGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default VehicleList
```

In my vehicle.js I have to show the info of the clicked vehicle, react is not showing anything on the screen and I'm lost at this point.

The code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Card, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import VehicleList from './VehicleList';
import {faker} from '@faker-js/faker'
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';

class Vehicles extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.manufacturer = this.faker.vehicle.manufacturer().bind(this)
  }
  render(){
  return(
<div>
<Card className="text-center">
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>No Vehicle Selected</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Click a vehicle to see more details
    </Card.Text>
  </Card.Body>
  </Card>
<br></br>
  <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src={`https://via.placeholder.com/180x150?text=${faker.vehicle.manufacturer()}
     ${faker.vehicle.model()}`} />
    <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{faker.vehicle.manufacturer()} {faker.vehicle.model()}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
      This is a wonderful {faker.vehicle.fuel()}-powered {faker.vehicle.color()} {faker.vehicle.type()}.
      </Card.Text>
      <Button variant="primary">Buy now!</Button>
    </Card.Body>
</Card>
</div>
)
}
}


export default Vehicles
```

I really appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Open the console and report the error please.

Comment: Vehicles.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: _faker_js_faker__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.faker.vehicle.manufacturer(...).bind is not a function
    at new Vehicles (Vehicles.js:9:1)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:14321:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19686:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21609:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4162:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4275:1)

Comment: at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27448:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26555:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26464:1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line in your constructor to `this.manufacturer = this.faker.vehicle.manufacturer.bind(this);`

Or remove it entirely, you aren't referencing `this.manufacturer` in your code anyways.